# What is the best way to solve the warning about different server & client styles based on react-spring?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-spring

I'm working with Next.js and using a react-spring library to get an animation for a bottomsheet component. It works, however there is a warning appears:

***Warning: Prop `style` did not match. Server: "transform:translate3d(0,Infinitypx,0)" Client: "transform:translate3d(0,652px,0)"***

I've carefully investigated this warning and know that it's about incorrect rendering of the HTML element on the server and on the client side. It's clear that on the server side there is no viewport height and thus react-spring can't calculate normally the final value and Next.js registers it as an one value with `Infinity` and then blames on the client side when the value is calculated correctly due to available viewport height.

*I'm wondering what is the best way to rid of this error?* 

Unfortunatelly I can't catch the react-spring calculation stage and to set a correct value.Tere is no API to do it and basically I just don't know the user's viewport height.

I've thinking about the using `indexOf` for the value and check if the `Infinity` presented and replace it for ex: by `0` 
however it still doesn't solve a problem as the final value will be different anyway.

Maybe someone has an idea or some link to docs etc. where I could find a solution for that? 
Basically it's just a warning but I'd like to fix it anyway.

Here is the example code:

```
import { a, config, useSpring } from '@react-spring/web';

export function BottomSheet({propsHeight}) {
  const finalHeight = propsHeight || height - 62;
  const display = y.to((py) => (py < finalHeight ? 'flex' : 'none'));
  const [{ y }, api] = useSpring(() => ({ y: finalHeight }));

  const open = (dragEvent?: any) => {
    const canceled = dragEvent?.canceled;
    // when cancel is true, it means that the user passed the upwards threshold
    // so need to change the spring config to create a nice wobbly effect
    api.start({
      y: 0,
      immediate: false,
      config: canceled ? config.wobbly : config.stiff,
    });
  };

  const close = (velocity = 0) => {
    api.start({
      y: finalHeight,
      immediate: false,
      onResolve() {
        if (onClose) {
          onClose();
        }
      },
      config: { ...config.stiff, velocity },
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // provide open/close actions to parent control
    getActions(open, close);
  }, []);

  // pseudo hmtl. Removed all other markup to simplify things
  return (<a.div
    style={{
      y, // Here is the problem of the server & client incorrect values
    }}
  />)

}
```

I highly appreciate any help!

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

The only one solution I've found so far for this use case it's rendering the component on client side only and, basically, it makes sense because this code is based on the browser API. I don't see any other possible solutions

To achieve it you can use dymanic imports and Next.js supports them well: [here is the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) 
You should disable the SSR in the import options and the component will be rendered on the client side only.

Like this:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const BottomSheetDynamic = dynamic(
  () =>
    import('@mylibrary/components/bottomsheet/BottomSheet').then(
       //this component doesn't have default import so should do it in this way
      (mod) => mod.BottomSheetexport
    ),
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);
```